# como converter Enum para string?

Tags: c#

Olá, quero listar os elementos da classe chamado, porém o Status é do tipo Enum, ao tentar converter para string, aparece a mensagem: "Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo 'string' em Enums.Status".
Código:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ChamadoViewModel>> ObterTodos()
    {
        var chamados = await _repository.ObterTodos();
        var chamadosView = new List<ChamadoViewModel>();

        foreach(var chamado in chamados)
        {
            chamadosView.Add(new ChamadoViewModel
            {
                IdOrigemUsuario = chamado.IdOrigemUsuario,
                IdUsuario = chamado.IdUsuario,
                IdOperadora = chamado.IdOperadora,
                DataChamado = chamado.DataChamado,
                HoraChamado = chamado.HoraChamado,
                Solicitadora = chamado.Solicitadora,
                NomeProfissional = chamado.NomeProfissional,
                Motivo = chamado.Motivo,
                Erro = chamado.Erro,
                Status = chamado.Status.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo 'string' em Enums.Status"* pela mensagem, nessa `ChamadoViewModel` a property `Status` é um enum e não string, dai está dando erro. Coloca a definição da classe na pergunta e também da classe que é o tipo da variável `chamados`, mas creio que você precisa converter um enum para outro enum. Se eles tiverem os mesmo valores, poderia converter para int antes, mas se forem diferente, e esse seria o mais recomendado, seria fazer um método que mapeasse os valores

Comment: @wrafanunes alguma novidade?

Answer (score 3):

No exemplo abaixo converto String para Enum e vice-versa. Espero ter ajudado.

```
using System;

namespace TestVoid
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var placeStr = "Home";

            var place = Places.School;

            Console.WriteLine(place);

            // Enum to String.
            placeStr = place.ToString();

            // String to Enum.
            // Enum.TryParse<Places>(placeStr, true, out place);

            Console.WriteLine(placeStr);
        }

        public enum Places{
            Home, Work, School
        }
    }
}
```